# Problem with Math.log and Math.pow expression

Tags: java

So I have this homework question where it asks me to make a power formula using  `e^(Y * log(X))` and my pow method. I have done my pow method and it works, just having some difficulty with the equation method.

For example, if I put in 7 and 5

I should get the answer 16806.9999999 for the expression and for my pow 16806. I'm not getting that answer for the expression.

```
double one;
double two;

System.out.println("Enter your first number");
one = sc.nextDouble();

System.out.println("Entr your second number");
two = sc.nextDouble();
sc.close(); 

System.out.println("using the formula your number is " + Math.log(Math.pow(one, 1) * Math.log(two)));
System.out.println("using myPow " + Math.pow(one, two));
```

Comment: I assume you have a typo when you say that 16806 is the result of 7^5. I confirmed with a calculator and suggested that edit but someone rejected it. It should be 16807.

Comment: Did you find the answer you were looking for?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you may have a wrong formula. Instead of `Math.log(Math.pow(one, 1) * Math.log(two))` you should have `Math.exp(two * Math.log(one))` maybe?